# youtube live video is not responding in android

Tags: android, youtube

This is my code so far:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
    YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {

static private final String DEVELOPER_KEY = "USER API KEY";
static private String VIDEO = "LIuk1qu0RlU";

private YouTubePlayerFragment youTubePlayerFragment;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    youTubePlayerFragment = (YouTubePlayerFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.youtubeplayerfragment);
    youTubePlayerFragment.initialize(DEVELOPER_KEY, this);
}

@Override
public void onInitializationFailure(Provider provider,
        YouTubeInitializationResult result) {

    if (result.isUserRecoverableError()) {
        result.getErrorDialog(this, 0).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(
                this,
                "YouTubePlayer.onInitializationFailure(): "
                        + result.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider,
        YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            "YouTubePlayer.onInitializationSuccess()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();


        player.cueVideo(VIDEO);


}
}
```

(recorded video is playing but live video is stopping my app)

I have tried `video id = all recorded videos` its working fine ..

when i tried `videoid =LIuk1qu0RlU`

it's not working, I have also tried other live video id

Comment: I Have exactly the same problem! And it was working like a couple of days aogo

Comment: It's bug from youtube download grade youtube app and it will work fine in kitkat